# Integrating Lync 2010 with an external program

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010

How can I integrate Lync 2010, with a program that does a DB look up and shows a small popup, with the information found, and also a few buttons with some options.
The program is already running with some other types of phone systems, I kind of need a connector for Lync.
I don't want to put a tab or other UI inside Lync.

Comment: Presumably this is a Screen-pop type app - i.e. it detects an incoming audio call, then pops up information about the caller?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And it also lets the user call out from a list, which derives from the DB. This call should be send to Lync, which then place the call.

Comment: I just saw that the example in 2010 SDK, AudioVideoConversation, is pretty much doing what I want, I'll investigate it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to start with the [Lync SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18898). You can build your app as a Winforms or WPF app.

**Signing In**

To connect and sign in to the running instance of Lync, check out [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20121005104622/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh345263.aspx) from the SDK. Make sure you keep a reference to the `LyncClient` object that represents Lync. This can be got by calling the static method `LyncClient.GetClient()`

**Detecting an incoming call**

To detect an incoming call, you can listen for the `ConversationManager.ConversationAdded` event. `ConversationManager` is a property on your `LyncClient` instance.

To determine if the call is a) an Audio call, and b) incoming (as opposed to an outgoing call placed by the user) you can use the following method:

```
bool IsIncomingAVCall(Conversation conversation)
{
    // Test to see if the call contains the AV modality
    bool containsAVModality = conversation.Modalities.ContainsKey(ModalityTypes.AudioVideo);

    if (containsAVModality)
    {
        // Get the state of the AV modality
        var state = conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].State;

        // 'Notified' means the call is incoming
        if (state == ModalityState.Notified) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the `ConversationAdded` event, you should sign up to the `Conversation.ParticipantAdded` event, so you can check who the caller is. The EventArgs object has a `Participant` property, which in turn has a `Contact` property. The `Contact` property has a number of properties including `Uri`, which should give you the phone number (if that's what you need).

You can then make your DB call and pop your info.

**Edit:** I've written a blog post about screen pops which goes into much more detail - [here](https://blog.chimusoftware.com/post/screen-pop-applications/)

**Placing a call**

If your app is WPF, the easiest way to allow a call to be placed is by using the [StartAudioCallButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436923.aspx) control. Otherwise, the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378563.aspx) should help.

Comment: Fantastic! I'll try your suggestions and also take a deeper look at the AudioVideoConversation example.

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to mark as answer (using the tick) if this solves your problem, to help anyone else browsing this question later - cheers

Comment: It can take a day or three to get there, but I'll remember. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I got it to work, thank for your help Paul, but how do I mark the answer?

Comment: Great, glad you got there! There should be a tick near the up and downvote buttons in the top/left of this answer that let's you accept this as the answer

Comment: Office 365 gives a good startup help for Lync 2010. Se Lab 9.3 and Lab 9.4. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14889

Comment: Brilliant response, some of the links are dead so i've updated them