# Execute Lync 2010 extension code before user accepts call

Tags: c#, .net, lync-2010, lync

I'd like to execute some custom code every time Lync 2010 receives a call. I tried it with a Conversation Window Extension (CWE), which contains a Silverlight client, and the Silverlight client uses the Lync API, like this:

```
var lync = LyncClient.GetClient();
lync.ConversionManager.ConversionAdded += ...
```

The problem is, this code gets executed only when the user accepts an incoming call. How can I execute code like this exactly in the moment when the call comes in? **Not** after the user accepts the call, but while "the phone rings"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, the extension will only be displayed when you have a conversation window to show it in - which means accepting the conversation first.

If you want to trap incoming calls you can do this with the Lync SDK - theres more info on exactly how to do this in the accepted answer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144519/integrating-lync-2010-with-an-external-program)

If you're trying to build a screen-pop type application, see [this post](https://blog.chimusoftware.com/post/screen-pop-applications/)

Comment: thanks, I implemented it using a background service which uses the Lync SDK