# Incoming call in Lync

Tags: c#, call, lync

I'm trying to detect an incoming call in the Lync client...
Very simple program, which must detect a call and do something(messagebox for example).

I have allready read similar thread: [Detecting an incoming call in Lync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207549/detecting-an-incoming-call-in-lync) , but still can't do that working.

So, how i can listen the ConversationManager.ConversationAdded event?

P.S. Can someone  provide a link to the  full working program that does something similar.I am new to programming and this is only my second program 
P.P.S. My English is not very well, sory)

Comment: "but still can't do that working" is rather broad - please read the faq and learn how to ask a question